# Layout quebrado no opera

Tags: bug, layout

Qualquer página que eu acesso do opera a barra laranjada ao lado direito fica atrás do rodapé no Meta.

Esta imagem é referente ao META:
[image: layout quebrado meta]

Já esta é referente ao SO no momento de editar um post:

[image: layout quebrado SO edit]

Comment: Acho que não é somente no Opera, no Firefox também: [imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtrOK.png). O problema ocorre na página https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: parece que corrigiram, ao menos para mim aparece normal @Renan

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento qual browser? Testei no FF54.0, Chrome 58 e Opera 46. Ambos aparecem como na imagem do Flávio.

Comment: @Renan deve ser "cache back-end", mesmo que eu tente pra mim ainda vai aparecer, testei no FF 54.0a2 e no Opera 45

Comment: @Renan atualizei para o Opera `46.0.2597.32 (PGO)` parece ok ainda, deve ser cache back-end, creio que logo atualize pra vcs corrigido ou atualize pra mim e cause o bug. Vamos esperar

Comment: Aqui o problema parou de acontecer.

Comment: Aqui ainda acontece, imagino que pode ter a ver com linux. @Renan qual é o seu sistema operacional ?

Comment: @FlávioGranato win10 x64, Firefox 54.0 (x64).